# Cannot Create Trigger on MYSQL AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a trigger on my database which is in a MYSQL AWS RDS instance. 
When I try the code below:

```
DELIMITER $$
USE database_name $$
CREATE DEFINER=oldloginuser@localhost trigger newtrigger after update on db_col
for each row
begin
  if new.hits != old.hits then
    insert into log(id, access_time) values (new.id, now());
  end if;
end
```

I get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1419. You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: did you read the error message? You need the `super` priv, or disable binary loggin.

Comment: @MarcB I understand the message however I don't know how to solve it on AWS RDS

Comment: See [How do I enable functions, procedures, and triggers for my Amazon RDS MySQL instance?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-functions/) and [Creating Triggers with Binary Logging Enabled Requires SUPER Privilege](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Troubleshooting.html#CHAP_Troubleshooting.MySQL.CreatingTriggers).

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the DB Parameter Group value.

you can change at RDS -> Select Database -> configuration -> DB Parameter Group -> click default parameter group you will be redirect to DB Parameter Group page -> create new DB Parameter Group with option

and reboot the db;